# Как создать поток (stream)-посредник в nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const stream2 = new Writable();
  stream2.result = [];
  stream2._write = function (chunk, enc, next) {
  this.result.push(chunk);
  next();
 };

  const stream1 = new Readable();
  stream1._read = function () {
    stream1.push(stream2.result.shift() || null);
  };

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    excelDoc.write(stream2).then(() => {
      zip.file('excelDoc.xlsx', stream1);
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
```

Может кто посоветовать грамотное решение проблемы?
Использую пакеты JsZip и exceljs. Второй умеет писать документ
в стрим, первый умеет читать из стрима и писать файл в архив.
Недавно очень быстро набросал такой костыль, так как и не смог разобраться.
Как можно было бы более грамотно построить мост между этими пакетами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи вам не нужно даже дополнительные пакеты ставить. Можно использовать обычный `PassThrough` stream.

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')

 // ваш код тут...
const stream = new PassThrough()
workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
zip.file('myfile.zip', stream)
// делаете что-то ещё.
```

Answer (score 0):

Потоки можно соединять напрямую, без промежуточного буфера. Что вам мешает вызвать `push` прямо из `_write`? Кроме того, имеет смысл использовать дуплексный поток чтобы не плодить сущности.

```
class BufferStream extends Duplex {
    constructor({ objectMode, highWaterMark }) {
        super({
            objectMode, 
            readableHighWaterMark = highWaterMark,
            writableHighWaterMark = 0, // можно и наоборот
        });
        this._callback = null;
    }

    _read() {
        this._callback && this._callback();
        this._callback = null;
    }

    _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        if (this.push(chunk)) 
            callback();
        else
            this._callback = callback;
    }

    _final(callback) {
       this.push(null);
       callback();
    }
}
```

Такой буфер можно использовать вот так:

```
const buffer = new BufferStream();
excelDoc.write(buffer);
zip.file('excelDoc.xlsx', buffer);
```

PS код не проверял, могут быть глупые ошибки по невнимательности